# Find Similar Word Pattern for Factor Variable using R

Tags: r, pattern-matching, similarity, r-factor

I have `Data` with `10 000 Observations`, variable named `Com`, type `Factor` with `3000 Levels`. What I'm trying to do here is to find similar pattern between values in variable `Com` and then combine it into one. So, I can do analysis on it later. The `str` of `Data` is as below:

```
> Data
 'data.frame':   10000 obs. of  1 variable:
  $ Com: Factor w/ 3000 levels
```

Example: `Frequency` of `Com`:

```
> Frequency<-data.frame(Com=c("C/C++ PROGRAMMING", "C; C++ PROGRAMMING", "C++ PROGRAMMING", "C++", "PROGRAMMING C++", "C", "C PROGRAMMING", "C, C++ PROGRAMMING", "PROGRAMMING IN C; C++", "PROGRAMMINGS IN C/C++","PROGRAMMING IN C/C++", "PROGRAMMING (C, C++, CUDA)"), Freq=c(2,3,3,1,2,5,6,2,1,3,4,5))
> Frequency
                                 Com   Freq
1                  C/C++ PROGRAMMING      2
2                 C; C++ PROGRAMMING      3
3                    C++ PROGRAMMING      3
4                                C++      1
5                    PROGRAMMING C++      2
6                                  C      5
7                      C PROGRAMMING      6
8                 C, C++ PROGRAMMING      2
9              PROGRAMMING IN C; C++      1
10             PROGRAMMINGS IN C/C++      3
11              PROGRAMMING IN C/C++      4
12        PROGRAMMING (C, C++, CUDA)      5       # Just add one more situation
```

I want the result of `Frequency` to be:

```
> Frequency
                                 Com   Freq
1                  C/C++ PROGRAMMING     15
2                    C++ PROGRAMMING      6
3                      C PROGRAMMING     11
4         PROGRAMMING (C, C++, CUDA)      5
```

I can recode the levels of `Com` in order to this. However, there are `3000 Levels` for this variable `(Com)` and I have to find it one by one which going to take my time.

So, is there any other method to do this without taking so much time?
I have tried looking at `Pattern matching and replacement in R`, but still can't solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in some steps using regular expressions:

```
dat$Freq <- as.numeric(dat$Freq)
dat$Com[grep('.*(C).*(C[++]).*',dat$Com)] <- 'ccplusplus'
dat$Com[grep('C[++]',dat$Com)] <- 'cplusplus'
dat$Com[grep('C',dat$Com)] <- 'c'
tapply(dat$Freq,dat$Com,sum)

# c ccplusplus  cplusplus 
# 11         15          6
```

Comment: Why I keep getting an error displaying: ` Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, grep(".*(C).*(C[++]).*", Frequency$Com),  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated `

Comment: You should coerce it to character before `Frequency$Com <- as.character(Frequency$Com)`

Answer (score 1):

From the package `stringr`, you might easily exploit `str_detect` and you can work by thinking of what the modalities you want to group together have in common.
I can guess it is a hard work, but I don't think that R can enter your mind and find what you consider "similar".

An example:

```
df$Com_grouped <- NA

df$Com_grouped <- ifelse(str_detect(df$Com, "C") & (!str_detect(df$Com, "C[++]")), "C PROGRAMMING", df$Com_grouped)
```

Finally: `tapply(df$Freq, df$Com_grouped, sum)`, so that you can get the frequencies.

Comment: Why I keep getting an error displaying: `Error in grepl("C++", c("C/C++ PROGRAMMING", "C; C++ PROGRAMMING", "C++ PROGRAMMING",  : 
  invalid regular expression 'C++', reason 'Invalid use of repetition operators'`

Comment: try with `"C[++]"` or directly `"[++]"`.